# What are the limitations of using gradient-free optimization functions?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, numerical-optimization

I have been using Nelder-Mead optimization function to obtain optimum weight values for cost function in simple linear and logistic regression cases, the advantage of this algorithm is that it doesn't require the user to supply the cost function gradients with respect to the weights (it feels like cheating).

So, are there any limitations or constraints for using optimization methods like Nelder-Mead's that do not require calculating gradients?

Comment: "it feels like cheating" -- It is not cheating. It is more like looking at a map when you want to get somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/98983/gradient-based-learning-algorithms-vs-global-optimization-learning-algorithms-fo

Comment: Not having to supply a gradient is also the case if you use numeric derivatives. That can work quite well with BFGS for example. One often cited disadvantage of methods that are not gradient based is that they may take more computation time before converging.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method): "However, the Nelder–Mead technique . . . can converge to non-stationary points" I consider this a pretty severe limitation.

Comment: "it feels like cheating" ------ It is not cheating, specially if your problem is a very hard one; we are always at disadvantage in this game against  god.

Comment: @user856  I haven't found an optimization method yet that doesn't have "severe limitations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general principle, gradient-based methods tend to converge significantly faster on smooth functions than gradient-free optimization methods. Also, while there are nice convergence guarantees for stochastic gradient descent on convex functions, it seems the convergence guarantees are quite limited for Nelder-Mead. See this paper on finally getting convergence guarantees for a variant in two dimensions, for example: http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/nm.pdf.